# Doctrine2 - Inheritance and relation

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is it possible to solve this problem in doctrine? I have one entity, called **Comment** and this entity have relation with another entity caller **Author**. The relation is made througt two columns: **author_id** and **author_type**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="comments")
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entities\Authors\Guest", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="author_id", nullable=FALSE),
     *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_type", referencedColumnName="author_type", nullable=FALSE)
     * })
     **/
    protected $author;
}
```

This relation is because author could be system user, guest, facebook user, etc. and each user have their own author id and author type (guest, system, facebook, etc.) so the author entity look like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="authors")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="author_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *         "guest"        = "Guest",
 *         "system"    = "System",
 *         "facebook"    = "Facebook",
 *         "twitter"    = "Twitter",
 *         "google"    = "Google",
 *         "github"    = "Github"
 * })
 */
class Guest
{
}
```

To separate each author type i use single table inheritance. with column **author_type**. Primary key for author table is **author_id** and **author_type**

When i load comment entity, it is successfully loaded with author, but problem is when i try to create new comment entity and store it to the database. The author_id stored in comment table is ok, but author_type is always "guest" even if correct author entity is added to the comment entity.

So is there possibility to solve this? Or should i use diffrent type of relation, add extra column etc.?

Comment: Is your Guest-Entity the topmost class of the hierarchy and are all other Entities extending Guest?

Comment: yes, Guest is top and all other (Facebook, System) are extending it